# Why bootstrap modal can't display on Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1.code of index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Add release', new_release_articles_path,  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
<div id="modal-window" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<p>Hoc javascript</p>
```

2. code of controller:

> ```
>  def new_release
>       respond_to do |format|
>         format.html
>         format.js
>       end
>     end
> ```

3. code of new_release.js.erb

> ```
> $('#modal-window').html("<%= j render 'blorgh/articles/new_release'%>");
> $('#modal-window').modal();
> ```

4. code of new_release.html.erb

> ```
> <div class="modal-header">
>    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
>    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
>  </div>
>  <div class="modal-body">
>    **here comes whatever you want to show!**
>  </div>
>  <div class="modal-footer">
>    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
>    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
>  </div>
> ```

5. application.js

> ```
> //= require rails-ujs
> //= require jquery
> //= require bootstrap
> //= require jquery_ujs
> //= require turbolinks
> //= require_tree .
> ```

6. Result click link add release:
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

You don't need `rails-ujs` if you use `jquery_ujs` so you can remove this `//= require rails-ujs` from here and follow the order

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

you can consider one `rails-ujs` or `jquery_ujs`, after changing this restart the server

**Update from comment**

Use `tabindex="-1"` to div modal window

Comment: Thank you, i removed rails-ujs, methought it had working, but it only display gray screen, not display dialog form.

Comment: I'm sorry. Has my html any problem, why not display dialog form?

Comment: I fixed by add tabindex="-1"  to div modal-window

Comment: Great to hear it :)